# Adding different Bootstrap-Scrollbars to different Div-Container

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**My Goal**

I want to use a good-looking scrollbar that i found on this website [Bootstrap Scrollbar](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/scroll/).

---

**My Problem**

However i am struggeling with the logic behind it.

Since a scrollbar is added automatically, where in the HTML do i have to locate the *bootstrap-scrollbar-div* ?

If I have for example 2 separate *div-containers* and I want in each of them to follow a certain *scrollbar-color*, how do i achieve it ?
Do i have to warp my 2 div-containers each within the *bootstrap-scrollbar* ?

*Note*:

- *If anything is unclear or if I formulated my question to unprecisely, leave a comment.*
- In the following code, the bootstrap is not working, this is the reason why i am asking this question.

---

**The Code-Snipped**

---

```css
.scrollbar-morpheus-den::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.scrollbar-morpheus-den::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.scrollbar-morpheus-den::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#30cfd0), to(#330867));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #30cfd0 0%, #330867 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #30cfd0 0%, #330867 100%);
}

.scrollbar-morpheus-den {
  scrollbar-color: #330867 #F5F5F5;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="scrollbar scrollbar-lady-lips">
    <div class="force-overflow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="test2">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
    et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
    tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
    sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
    no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
    dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if add class `scrollbar-morpheus-den` to `<div>` tag?

e.g. `<div class="test2 scrollbar-morpheus-den">`

I have added the `height: 100px;` and `overflow: auto;` to class `.test` so that overflow happens with the content available.

```css
.scrollbar-morpheus-den::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.scrollbar-morpheus-den::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.scrollbar-morpheus-den::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#30cfd0), to(#330867));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #30cfd0 0%, #330867 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #30cfd0 0%, #330867 100%);
}

.scrollbar-morpheus-den {
  scrollbar-color: #330867 #F5F5F5;
}

.test2 {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="scrollbar scrollbar-lady-lips">
    <div class="force-overflow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="test2 scrollbar-morpheus-den">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
    et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
    tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
    sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
    no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
    dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```